# Finite topological generation of Galois groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-theory

Let $F/\mathbf{Q}$ be an extension of finite degree, and let $S$ be a finite set of places of $F$.  Let $F_S/F$ be the maximal extension unramified outside $S$; what is the most natural way to see that $\mathrm{Gal}(F_S/F)$ is topologically finitely generated?

Comment: Variations of this question have been coming up once a week lately -- why?

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/63029/finitely-generated-galois-groups

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/63094/criteria-for-topologically-finitely-generated-profinite-groups/63104#63104



Answer (score 9):

As far as I know, in general it is an open problem to establish whether $\mathrm{Gal}(F_S/F)$ is topologically finitely generated. For example, this question is posed as a conjecture (attributed to Shafarevich) in [these notes](http://www.math.polytechnique.fr/~chenevier/coursIHP/chenevier_lecture1.pdf) of Chenevier (see Conjecture 1.7).

Comment: Whoops! I'm not quite sure why I thought this was true.

Comment: To be honest, a few minutes after writing my answer I wondered if I had misinterpreted your question and you were actually asking for the most natural strategy to attack the problem for a GIVEN number field $F$ and a GIVEN finite set $S$ of places of $F$...